# What is $\frac{\partial(\frac{d(x(t))}{dt})}{(\partial x(t))}$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule, scalar-fields

> What is $$\frac{\partial(\frac{d(x(t))}{dt})}{(\partial x(t))}$$ ?

I came across this while trying to find the second derivative of $$u(t)=f(X(t),Y(t))$$.

Edit:
When we are taking the second derivative, we have 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} y') x' + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x' +  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} y') y'$$

but, for example, in the first part when we are to take the derivative of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x'$ respect to x, we should get $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} x' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}$ but I don't know what $\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}$ is .

Comment: See whether this helps you in any way: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954073/derivative-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function

Comment: @Rohan There is a big problem in the answer to that question, but thanks in any way.

Comment: @Leth When you take the second derivative , do it according to $t$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam yes,

Answer (score 0):

We have

$df(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)dy$

hence

$$u'(t)=\frac{df(X(t),Y(t))}{dt}$$

$=f'_x(X(t),Y(t))X'(t)+f'_y(X(t),Y(t))Y'(t)$

and

$u''(t)=X'( f''_{xx}X'+f''_{xy}Y'   )$

$+X''f'_x$

$+Y'(f''_{yx}X'+f''_{yy}Y')$

$+Y''f'_y$

Comment: there is no problem in there, problem begins in the second derivative.

Comment: I hope you are adding the "..." into the answer :)

Comment: I have already know the answer, but don't know the why the answer is this :). I will edit my question so that you can see where my problem is.

Comment: I edited the question