# What is derivative of a derivative of function with respect to the function?

Tags: calculus

How do I evaluate this:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)
$$
given that $x$ is function of $t$

Comment: What are your thoughts, and what have you tried? Is there a specific function $x(t)$ that you're interested in? That will make this easier.

Comment: HINT:  Apply the chain rule.

Comment: Do you know how what it means for a function between (possibly infinite dimensional) topological vector spaces to be differentiable? Here I would view $x\mapsto \frac{dx}{dt}$ as a map from $C^\infty(\Bbb R)\to C^\infty(\Bbb R)$, or as a map from $C^1_0(\Bbb R)\to C_0(\Bbb R)$. Is this the kind of context you are expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivative of a function with respect to another function.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954073/derivative-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the Chain Rule to express the $d/dx$ with respect to $t$.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}}
$$