# Derivative of a function w.r.t another function

Tags: derivatives

I have the function $f(X)$, $X$: depend to a variable $\theta $. is there a direct expression to calculate the derivative of $f(X)$ with respect to $\theta$:

$$\frac{df(X)}{d\theta} $$

And I want to provide me with some references if you would.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivative of a function with respect to another function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954073/derivative-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta},$$

that is, you first differentiate the outer function $f$ wrt. to the inner function $x$, and then differentiate the inner function wrt. to the variable you're originally differentiating wrt. (here $\theta$), and then you multiply them to get the desired result.

*EDIT, as response to OPs edit:*

It seems you are looking for the so-called [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), where a hard d is used:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}.$$

Note that $$\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} \theta}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta},$$ as $x$ only depends on $\theta$ (at least, this is assumed from the information given).

Comment: I found some references that they use this expression : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \frac{\partial X}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} $, Is it true and  What is the difference between it and your expression.

Comment: @user137684, just superficially that expression does not make sense, because you ought to be able to cancel $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ on both sides, ensuring that the other term is always 0. Are you sure that's what you read?

Comment: Sorry I made I mistake (difference between $d$ and $\partial$), and I updated my post  $\frac{d f}{d \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \frac{d X}{d \theta} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$.

Comment: @user137684 See my update.

Comment: @ Lovsovs, Thanks for your answer. Last thing I think in right hand side of your updated expression first part, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ is the correct.

Comment: @user137684 Yes of course, thank you! :)

Comment: @user137684 If you liked the answer, you can upvote and/or accept it. If it didn't answer your question, please do let me know where it left you wanting. Cheers.