# Does it make sense to take the derivative of f(x) with respect to g(x)?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = \cos(x)$.

Then I want to find the derivative of sin(x) with respect to cos(x).

So I have:

$$\frac{d\sin(x)}{d\cos(x)}$$

$d/dx \sin(x) = \cos(x)$, so $d\sin(x) = \cos(x)dx$.

$d/dx \cos(x) = -\sin(x)$, so $d\cos(x) = -\sin(x)dx$.

Then,

$$\frac{d\sin(x)}{d\cos(x)} = \frac{\cos(x)dx}{-\sin(x)dx} = -\cot(x)$$

Is this legit or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivative of a function with respect to another function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954073/derivative-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function)

Answer (score 1):

We have:$$\frac{d(\sqrt{1-\cos^2x})}{d(\cos x)}$$Substitute $u=\cos(x)$:

$$\frac{d}{du}(\sqrt{1-u^2})$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: $\frac {-2u} {2\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac {-\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}=-\cot x \csc x$

Comment: @Stacker it is $\frac{-\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}=-\cot x$

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing it out